# Org table date arithmetic with Lisp expressions

Tags: org-mode, org-table

It's easy to do date arithmetic using org-mode table formulas.  For example, if I enter this table:

```
| [2020-01-01] | |
| [2020-02-01] | |
| [2020-03-01] | |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1+1
```

...and then do `C-c C-c` on the formula, the table updates column 2, adding one day to the dates in column 1.

Can this be done using a Lisp formula instead of a calc formula?  If so, how?

I see in the org-mode manual that Lisp formulas support various trailing flags to interpret the table cells in different formats, but not datestamps.  I experimented with `calc-eval`, but calc datestamps differ in format from org datestamps.  It appears there's some invisible plumbing that connects the two.

Comment: Example: `(org-format-time-string "[%F]" (org-time-from-absolute (1+ (org-time-string-to-absolute "[2020-01-01]"))))`

Comment: The basic idea behind @Tobias's example is that entries in an Org mode table are passed to a lisp expression as strings: the rest is a matter of converting them to a data type that you can use for calculation, do the calculation and then convert the result back to a string in order to store it in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `org-table-eval-formula` to do the calculation in-place of the field and then retrieve the field value which the lisp form must return with `org-table-get-field`.
In that way you can evaluate the calc formula within your lisp form.

In lisp formulae $1 delivers a string `"[2020-01-01]"` for the date `[2020-01-01]`. Therefore the somewhat awkward construction of the calc formula `(concat $1 "+1")`.

See the following example:

```
| [2020-01-01] |  |
| [2020-02-01] |  |
| [2020-03-01] |  |
#+TBLFM: $2='(progn (org-table-eval-formula nil (concat $1 "+1") t t t t) (org-table-get-field))
```

---

In this special case where you really only want date calculation you can also use the following Elisp formula instead:

```
| [2020-01-01] | [2020-01-02] |
| [2020-02-01] | [2020-02-02] |
| [2020-03-01] | [2020-03-02] |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-format-time-string "[%F]" (org-time-from-absolute (1+ (org-time-string-to-absolute $1))))
```